# AES encryption using Verilog

Tags: aes, verilog, fpga

So I took it upon myself to learn all about the FPGA this semester. To test my skills, I picked up a project to encrypt and decrypt files using a FPGA implementation of the age old AES. Now implementation of AES using Verilog has been done umpteen times and for my reference I used the code at http://opencores.org/project,systemcaes. What I wish to do is use the Verilog file handling functions to read a small file, use it as input to the encryption block on the FPGA, and save the encrypted file back on the computer. I am aware that this can be done on the testbench(though I have not attempted it, I am sure it can be done). But how do I do the same when I implement the code on the FPGA board? Is there a way to select the file to be encrypted/decrypted and pass it onto the board? Is it even possible? 
Sorry if I come across as a noobie, its my first time in the world of FPGAs. Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Depending on how big the file is you may be able to cheat and just preload the file into an fpga ROM or something, if you'd rather spend time writing AES code than dealing with a filesystem and PC interface.

Comment: Thanks for the prompty reply Tim. Well I am almost done with the AES code, so no worries there. I only wish to transfer a small file, such as a small text file containing a few lines. But how would I go about preloading this file into the ROM? Is there some code for that or is done using ISE? For clarification, my target device is a Diligent Spartan 3E board.

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand that the FPGA will only take a description of the hardware that you are going to build. It is not like a programming language.

So if you want to load data into a memory on the FPGA you need a way to move the data from you PC into the FPGA. The easiest way is to implement an UART on the FPGA so you can communicate with a serial port on your PC. Then you load data from some terminal program on your PC into the FPGA.

Then you can use the serial port to read the data back to your PC.

This of course require you to have implemented the hardware needed to read and write things to and from a memory in your FPGA.

It might also be that you can stream data through the FPGA. But then I think I would use two serial ports.

Comment: Thanks a lot AxelOmega. After cruising through a load of other posts, I eventually got to know that such data must be transferred using UART or USB. My Spartan 3E board has both, so I am all up for using any of them. However, I could not find any resources detailing this procedure. How would I load the data using UART or USB? Could you please point me to some tutorial or atleast give an example so that I can get started? I am fully done with the AES code, and the testbench too, so the interfacing is all that remains.

Answer (score 0):

Verilog RTL does not have a concept of a file system, you would need the FPGA 'driver' to break the file down and send it over byte by byte or load it into a memory for the program on the FPGA to read.

I am not experienced with FPGAs, my under standing is that you synthesis the design and stream it into the FPGA. I thought that you might have still had some connectivity to the device where you were able to stream data to it. In the same way I think you can control the Arduino over USB.

How do you plan on getting the data back out of the FPGA? Do your tools allow you access to send and load data?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. What exactly is this 'driver' that you speak of? And how would I use it to break the file down without using the Verilog R/W commands and load it into the memory? Sorry if I am asking too many questions.